# Нужно увидеть какие связи в бд

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Нужно увидеть какие связи в бд, экспортирована в SQL с помощью браузера БД для SQLite, после этого запустил ее в workbanch и не могу найти как включить нужную функцию, подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переходите в раздел Models, выбираете пункт "Create EER Model from Database"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше с помощью мастера выбираете нужные параметры, и указываете БД

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]